# C#, EF6 - Replace Required attribute by fluent api

Tags: api, entity-framework-6, fluent

I want to replace the [Required] attribute on the Gig property of the class Notification with the following fluent api expression.

```
public class NotificationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Notification>
{
    public NotificationConfiguration()
    {
        Property(n => n.Gig).IsRequired();
    }   
}
```

If I do so, the compiler throws an error CS0453:

```
The type 'Gig' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'StructuralTypeConfiguration'<Notification>.Property<T>(Expression<Func<Notification, T>>)'
```

I cannot see the reason, why this isn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake ;-)
Gig is an object with a table representation, so this must be a navigation property to that table instead of a required field. So the code looks like this:

```
public class NotificationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Notification>
{
    public NotificationConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(n => n.Gig);
    }
}
```